# React Mapping through an array not working

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, expo

### Im working on a journal app and i need to map through a list of 'days' but it doesn't render them

Heres my JournalScreen.tsx: 
I have a testing array journal where i set a basic 'day' 
I want to map through but it doesn't work

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, Linking, Platform } from 'react-native';
import JournalCard from '../components/JournalCard';
import { View } from '../components/Themed';

import { RootTabScreenProps } from '../types';

export default function JournalScreen({ navigation }: RootTabScreenProps<'Journal'>) {
  const [journal, setJournal] = React.useState([
    {
      date: "29.09.21",
      value: "Today was a nice day this is also a Placeholder"
    }
  ])

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {
        journal.map((journal) => {
          <JournalCard key="i" value={journal} />
        })
      }
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

and here's my JournalCard.tsx:
It's very basic just the props and some text not much to say

```
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Pressable } from 'react-native';
import { Text, View } from './Themed';
import { Audio } from 'expo-av';
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";
import Colors from '../constants/Colors';
import useColorScheme from '../hooks/useColorScheme';

type JournalCardProps = {
    value: any
}

export default function JournalCard({ value }: JournalCardProps) {
    const colorScheme = useColorScheme()

    return (
        <View style={[styles.container, { backgroundColor: Colors[colorScheme].uiBg }]}>
            <Text style={styles.date}>{value.date}</Text>
            <Text>{value.value}</Text>
        </View>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        width: '90%',
        padding: 10,
        borderRadius: 5
    },
    date: {
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        fontSize: 26,
        marginBottom: 20,
        borderBottomWidth: 2
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You're not returning anything inside your `map`. You have two options:

Remove the `{ }`

```
journal.map((journal) => <JournalCard key="i" value={journal} />)
```

Or, explicitly return:

```
journal.map((journal) => {
          return <JournalCard key="i" value={journal} />
})
```

Comment: Thank you didn't know I have to do that, in reactjs its without the return.

Comment: This is not specific to react -- this is Javascript language syntax in general